# Haskell do syntax and I/O

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I was playing around with a simple program in Haskell:

```
hello :: String -> String
hello s = "Hello, " ++ (trim s) ++ "!\n"

trim :: String -> String
trim [] = []
trim s = head $ words s

main :: IO()
main = do putStr "\nPlease enter your name: "
          name <- getLine
          hstring <- return $ hello name
          putStr hstring
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
Please enter your name: John Doe
Hello, John!
```

This works as expected when I load the program into ghci.  However when I compile the program using

```
ghc -o hello.exe hello.hs
```

it starts, waits for input, and then prints both prompts at the same time:

```
John Doe
Please enter your name: Hello, John!
```

Why is the behavior different between the interactive environment and compiler, and how can I make the compiler do what I want?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `main = putStr "Please enter your name:" >> getLine >>= putStr . hello` - just for fun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something of an FAQ.  Your lines are being buffered.  Use:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    ...
```

Also, your code is a bit... unique.  For example, you say:

```
hstring <- return $ hello name
putStr hstring
```

When you could do:

```
let hstring = hello name
putStr hstring
```

or just:

```
putStr $ hello name
```

Comment: Judicious use of `hFlush stdout` is a good option when disabling all buffering is excessive.

Comment: I still don't get why the code posted in the question results in that faulty output. Aren't the actions in the do-notation supposed to be sequenced ?

Comment: @is7s, that's what I thought as well.

Comment: @is7s: They are, but as TomMD said, the output is line buffered. So if you do `putStr "bla" >> someOtherAction`, `putStr "bla"` does execute first, but it won't be visible until the output stream is flushed, so it appears as if the `putStr` didn't execute until that happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot this made it clear. What confused me was that I thought what TomMD proposed in his answer (besides the buffering issue) are solutions to the problem

Comment: @is7s `hSetBuffering` and `hFlush` are solutions.  The talk about `hello name` is just a stylistic point that is functionally equivalent to what astay13 already had.

Comment: @TomMD, your solution works great, thanks so much!  Also, thanks for the stylistic advice - I'm not too comfortable with monads and do syntax. :)